# asking new vs editing already answered

Tags: discussion, questions

What are the guidelines for asking a new question with additional information as opposed to editing an already answered question?

For example, [Passing multiple generic interfaces to a method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14941947/299327) is an original and already answered question. [Use a list of generic interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14962110/299327) is an updated version of the same question with more code/detail.

What would be the best practice in this situation?

Comment: Looks to me like those two questions worked out OK.  They look like materially different questions, and if you edit the original one, you invalidate all of the existing answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the original problem is solved and you need help with the next step, accept and ask a new question.

If the original problem is still unsolved and people misunderstood the problem, didn't pay attention to the question or asked for more information, improve the question.

However, you certainly shouldn't revise a question so drastically that answers that used to be good no longer address the question at all. This has the unfair effect of making the answerers' efforts look bad.